# OLAP PivotTable Filter with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, olap-cube

I'm trying to build a string of project numbers and then pass that string through as the .VisibleItemsList of an OLAP pivot table. I've seen various posts about this where I believe it has worked fine but I'm getting some errors. Simplified code below:

```
Sub test()

Dim wks As Worksheet: Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("test wks")
Dim ProjStr As String

wks.Activate

    ProjStr = """[Project].[PROJECT_NUMBER].&[200283.0.001.01.000]"""
    
    wks.PivotTables("pt_test").PivotFields( _
        "[Project].[PROJECT_NUMBER].[PROJECT_NUMBER]").VisibleItemsList = Array(ProjStr) 'does not work
        
    wks.PivotTables("pt_test").PivotFields( _
        "[Project].[PROJECT_NUMBER].[PROJECT_NUMBER]").VisibleItemsList = Array("[Project].[PROJECT_NUMBER].&[200283.0.001.01.000]") 'works fine

End Sub
```

I'm getting this error:
[image]

I'm trying this with one project but when I build a string of multiple projects, I get a run time error of "Query(1,52) The syntax for ',' is incorrect" with the 52th character being the first comma. Example of the String I'd create with mulitple projects below:

```
ProjStr = """[Project].[PROJECT_NUMBER].&[200283.0.001.01.000]""" & ", " & """[Project].[PROJECT_NUMBER].&[200283.0.001.02.000]"""
```

That said, from everything I can tell, the ProjStr is formatted the same way as the code when I record a macro with multiple projects selections (other than all of the line breaks).

Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: I see a similarly themed thread here but no confirmed solution: http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?61439-OLAP-Pivot-Table-Variable-number-of-filters

Answer (score 0):

check extra quotations mark

```
ProjStr = """[Project].[PROJECT_NUMBER].&[200283.0.001.01.000]"""

VisibleItemsList = Array(ProjStr)
Debug.Print VisibleItemsList(0)

'result above is not the same below
'because there are extra quotations mark

VisibleItemsList = Array("[Project].[PROJECT_NUMBER].&[200283.0.001.01.000]")
Debug.Print VisibleItemsList(0)

'your string should be formated like this
ProjStr = "[Project].[PROJECT_NUMBER].&[200283.0.001.01.000],[Project].[PROJECT_NUMBER].&[200283.0.001.02.000]"
VisibleItemsList = Split(ProjStr, ",")
Debug.Print VisibleItemsList(0) & "," & VisibleItemsList(1)

'but I'd recomend to fill array item by item with ReDim Preserve and so on
'this will eliminate comma escaping problems and other special characters surprise
```